# How to choose objects for your android application?

Tags: android, class, object

I am new to Android but not to programming. I have taken C++ in school and we have been taught how to create objects, but not how to build robust programs using multiple objects. So you can see that using java to build Android apps leaves me with questions.....

1. thinking like an object oriented programmer, do i just shop through a list of classes until i find ones that i think would suite my app
2. is there a definite method of choosing the best classes for your project
3. do i find an app similar to the one i am trying to create and try to find what classes they used

any thoughts appreciated!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to learn (for me, at least) is by making small incremental changes to an example so I can how all the various elements of it work.
Download the examples (listed [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html)) - but accessible from your AVD and SDK manager tool from within Eclipse (Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager).
Start by modifying those examples. They are the best possible examples you can get for much of what you will want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you start with [Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) and also read about [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) - they should get you started. Also browsing [Classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html) is useful if you like wading through lots of technical docs (I do). Those three links are definitely worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Well first when building Android applications you need to:

1. Figure out what your application will be, and how it would work.
2. Next you would need to find out how you will implement the android classes.
3. i would recommend first reading a book on Android development. One that really helped me and made me an advance developer was [CommonsWare](http://commonsware.com/)
4. You should really get these books. When you finish you will be well on your way.